How to change the ip address of "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter"
I am looking at the network adapters in Control Panel -> Network & Sharing -> on the left, there is a "Change adapter settings".
I selected the network adapter that I wanted to change -> Properties -> Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
I set the IP Address to be 192.168.3.4 and the subnet automatically gets filled in to be 255.255.255.0. As soon as I click "OK", it pops up an alert box and says,

The IP address 192.168.3.4 you have entered for this network adapter is already assigned to another adapter 'Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2" on this computer. If the same address is assigned to both adapters and they both become active, only one of them will use this address. This may result in incorrect system configuration.


Do you want to fix the problem by entering a different IP address for this adapter in the list of IP addresses in the Advanced dialog box?

No, I would not like to change the IP address to fit your crap. I need to use this specific one for the device I need to use. Let me take that one and you switch your crap to fit my needs.
So I disabled the service in the device manager in hopes that when I assign that IP address to that 192.168.3.4 to that network adapter that the windows wi-fi service would automatically select a different IP address, but it doesn't do that. It won't overwrite the network device with that IP address, or at least when it does, when I check to see if it did, it blanks it out again.
I couldn't find a specific question on how to do this, probably because I couldn't think of the proper phrasing, so if anyone could direct me to an answered question on how to do this (or post an answer), I would appreciate it.

I solved this by:
Disabling both "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" and "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2", followed by an ipconfig /release, then when I went in to change the network adapter's IP address, the prompt was slightly different. It essentially said "would you like to take IP address of the network adapter that is no longer enabled?", and I said yes.

Perhaps beginning this with "I solved this by..." will help make it more clear from the beginning that this is an answer to your own question.

Got it. Will add it.
